# How to use my static library (.a) in swift 3

Tags: c, swift, static-libraries

I want to buid and use static library (.a) in swift 3. example: i build a 
lib helloLib.a, and use it.

hello.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "hello.h"
int printHello()
{
    printf("hello wourl");
    return 0;
}
```

hello.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
int printHello();
```

build to: libHello.a and copy to /usr/local/lib

Code swift

module.modulemap

```
module hello [system] {
    header "hello.h"
    link "libhello"
    export *
}
```

Package.swift

```
import PackageDescription
let package = Package(
    name: "hello",
    dependencies: []
)
```

use module hello

main.swift

```
import hello

printHello()
```

build with swift (command): swift build

get an error:

> Compile Swift Module 'usehello' (1 sources)
>
> Linking ./.build/debug/usehello
>
> ld: library not found for -llibhello for architecture x86_64
>
> :0: error: link command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> :0: error: build had 1 command failures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have omitted a lot of information about what you did, which makes it difficult to provide an answer with certainty.  Did you do something along the lines of https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md? What is your directory structure?  Where is hello.h?

Anyway, judging from the error message, one problem is that you use

```
   link "libhello"
```

in `module.modulemap`.  It is unclear what the name of the static library is.  It cannot be called `helloLib.a`, its name must start with `lib`.  If it is called `libhelloLib.a`, then in the module map it must be

```
link "helloLib"
```

You may also want to add the `-Xlinker -L/usr/local/lib` option as suggested in another answer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i rename libhello.a to libhelloLib.a  and  change to link "helloLib", compile it's ok. but get warning:   

ld: warning: object file (/usr/local/lib/libhelloLib.a(hello.o)) was built for newer OSX version (10.11) than being linked (10.10)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not finding your static library in /usr/local/lib. You should build with compiler flags such as:

```
swift build -Xcc -I/usr/local/include -Xlinker -L/usr/local/lib
```

Comment: it doesn't work, error :  
>
library not found for -llibhello for architecture x86_64

.i don't understand "-llibhello"

Comment: duck, if I understand it correctly, then your code for 'hello' will be result in a 'libhello.a' library.